# Facebook Authenticate - PassportJS - Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, proxy, passport.js

My passportJs application run at my home network(on localhost), but its not running different networks(my office).

I think I need set some Proxy settings *(Because we use proxy server on office, and we have proxy user-pass, Some application using this proxy settings(npm, git, eclipse update vs), But I dont know how to make settings on passportjs or Nodejs App.)*.

**My app.js configuration :**

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'my_precious' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Documentation Page (Sample Example): http://mherman.org/blog/2013/11/10/social-authentication-with-passport-dot-js/

**Error :**

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
>       at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (C:\DDiski\nodejs\passport-examples-master\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:340:17)
>       at C:\DDiski\nodejs\passport-examples-master\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:173:43
>       at C:\DDiski\nodejs\passport-examples-master\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:162:18
>       at ClientRequest. (C:\DDiski\nodejs\passport-examples-master\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:133:5)
>       at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
>       at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Socket.onerror (tls.js:1445:17)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       at net.js:441:14

**- How can I run this application on my office network?**  How can I **set proxy settings**?

Comment: Have the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Can you access the facebook auth https URLS from the same host?